# How do I make a GUI looking like this?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I need to make a GUI that looks like the one below

Comment: This is a java swing gui. Anyone who put in more then 20 minutes could research how to do this.

Comment: Also consider [`JCalendar`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jcalendar/info).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) . In particular, the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html). You need to use

[JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html), [JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [JSpinner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) as well as a [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) to organize them.

If you need help in layout, try to use the Matisse Builder in NetBeans. There probably is something similar in Eclipse too.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily make a GUI like that in the screenshot designing it with [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) and using [GroupLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.html) as layout manager for example, otherwise you can use Netbeans.